# On sum of elements in products of matrices for a simple graph

Tags: graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

Let $G$ be a simple graph with vertex set $\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n\}$. The adjacency matrix of $G$ is the 0-1 matrix
$A$, where $A_{i,j}=1$ when $v_i$ is adjacent with $v_j$. The degree matrix is the diagonal matrix $D$ where $D_{i,i}$ is the degree of $v_i$.

It seems that for any graph $G$,  the sum of elements in any product of any $A$'s and any $D$'s (in any order) is always  even. Can any one give a proof for this observation? Is it a known result? Note that the sum of elements in any power of $A$ (or $D$ ) is even, giving the first evidence to the above observation.

For example, consider $$A=
\left(
\begin{matrix}
0&0&1&1\\
0&0&1&0\\
1&1&0&1\\
1&0&1&0\\
\end{matrix}
\right),
D=\left(
\begin{matrix}
2&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&3&0\\
0&0&0&2\\
\end{matrix}
\right).$$
One can verifies that $e^TAe=8,e^TDe=8,\ldots,e^TADAAADe=422,\ldots$ are all even, where $e=(1,1,1,1)^T$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is false.

Here is a graph and some code in Sage to compute the sum of elements of $AADAAD$ which appears to be odd.

[image: 8-vertex graph]

I tried to prove it for a while, failed, so then decided to try some randomised searching on smallish graphs.

```
x = Graph('G?B@dW')
A = x.adjacency_matrix()
D = matrix.diagonal([x.degree(v) for v in x.vertices()])
j = matrix([1 for i in range(x.num_verts())])
j*(A*A*D*A*A*D)*j.transpose()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It seems that the parity of sums depends heavily on strings chosen. In some cases, the results are always even. I have failed to find even a counterexample using Mathematica. Maybe I used  some bad strings such as 'ADAAD'. When I change it to AADAAD as you suggested, it does give a few graphs with sums odd. Thanks again.

Comment: At first sight I thought that the statement should either be obviously true or obviously false, so the fact that it took a little effort to find a counterexample makes me wonder if there is something interesting there.

Comment: The entries of such products are counting homomorphisms from a graph $H$ determined by the string to the fixed graph $G$. So if the number of homomorphisms from $H$ to $G$ is even independent of $G$ (e.g., if $H$ is just an edge), then the sum of the entries will be even. To determine $H$, let $K_2$ be a complete graph on the two vertices $a$ and $b$. Then $A_{uv}$ is the number of homomorphisms from $K_2$ to $G$ where $a,b$ get mapped to $u,v$ respectively, and $D_{uv}$ is the number of homomorphisms where $a,a$ gets mapped to $u,v$ respectively (thus the zeros off the diagonal).

Comment: For products see here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/335072/correspondence-between-matrix-multiplication-and-a-graph-operation-of-lovasz